# Load a DataGridView using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq-to-sql

How can I use Linq-To-SQL to load a DataGridView?

Would the following work?

```
DCDataContext db = new DCDataContext();
dataGridViewJobs.DataSource = db.jobs.Select(p => p.closeDate <= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: call dataGridViewJobs.DataBind();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But you should change your query, since select is not used for querying like in sql but for projecting the elements of a sequence into a new form.

The following example should work:

```
   DCDataContext db = new DCDataContext();
    dataGridViewJobs.DataSource = (from jobs in db.jobs
                                    where p.closeDate <= DateTime.Now
                                    select jobs);
```

Comment: the dataGridView dosn't have a DataBind method. 
This is the grid view for forms no asp.net.

Comment: Sorry, but you have a tag for asp .net and the questions asks for a GridView not a DataGridView

Comment: @unknown (google)  : Please mention this fact in your question. How will he know it is asp.net or winforms using that two lines of code.

Comment: Apologize, I make the suggestions

Answer (score 2):

**Winforms :**

Alternately You can use BindingSource and DataGridView. You can give your Linq to SQL entity as DataSource to BindingSOurce. BindingSource will work as Datasource to DataGridView.

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = items;
dataGridView1.DataSource  = bindingSource1;
```

You can find how To [here](http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=435).
[image]

**ASP.Net** :

Yes it will work.
Please check [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/TestSite.aspx) for step by step How to.

[image]